# How to use php tag with conditional logic in WooCommerce function

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, code-snippets

I have a code to display checkbox on my single product pages in my WooCommerce shop. I want to only execute it for 2 product categories, unfortunately when I try to merge my code with conditional logic, I get a syntax error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?>' in [...]/functions.php on line 257

This is my code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_quantity', 'checkbox-eco-packaging', 35 );
   
function checkbox-eco-packaging() {   
 
 if( has_term( array( 'sneakers', 'backpacks' ), 'product_cat' ) {
    // do something if product is either in category "sneakers" or "backpacks"
 
   ?>
   <label><input type="checkbox" name="eco-pack" value="Yes">♻️ Eco packaging?</label>
    <?php
    
    } 
    
    /**
    else {
    // do something else if it isn't
    }
    **/
    
}
```

And it does work (but on all product pages) without the conditional logic:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_quantity', 'checkbox-eco-packaging', 35 );
   
function checkbox-eco-packaging() {   

   ?>
   <label><input type="checkbox" name="eco-pack" value="Yes">♻️ Eco packaging?</label>
    <?php 
    
}
```

How to use the php tag with conditional logic correctly in this case? Thank you in advance for any tips.

Comment: You are missing one closing bracket `)`. It should be `if( has_term( array( 'sneakers', 'backpacks' ), 'product_cat' ) ) {`

Comment: amazing, thank you! solved! how can I mark your answer, I cant find the checkmark here?